# playonlinux crashing on Fedora 19

Tags: fedora, python, wine, bugs

I installed playonlinux using the default repository and when I run the command `'playonlinux'` its getting crash and prints this output

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "mainwindow.py", line 34, in <module>
    import wx, wx.aui
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/wx-2.8-gtk2-unicode/wx/__init__.py", line 45, in <module>
    from wx._core import *
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/wx-2.8-gtk2-unicode/wx/_core.py", line 4, in <module>
    import _core_
ImportError: /lib/libgbm.so.1: undefined symbol: wayland_buffer_is_drm
/usr/share/playonlinux/playonlinux: line 144: python2.6: command not found
```

Do anyone know a solution for this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've solved this issue.

I've installed wxPython and wxWidget packages.

```
sudo yum install wxPython wxWidget
```

If above doesn't correct the problem, download the wxPython source and compile and install

after that I've installed libgbm

```
sudo yum install mesa-libgbm mesa-libgb-devel
```

Now, playonlinux works fine on Fedora 19